# How to import Primefaces's into Eclipse as source code

Tags: eclipse, maven, primefaces

Recently Primefaces [moved from Google Code to GitHub](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3505), so theoretically it's possible to fork its repository, make changes and submit a pull requests. I'd tried but I'm stuck.

As I understand I should import Primefaces into Eclipse as a separate Java Project and define in my JSF project dependency to it rather then to **primefaces.jar**.

I have tried to download it from GitHub as a zip file and import as maven project into Eclipse but get error that it requires [maven-jsf-plugin](https://github.com/primefaces/maven-jsf-plugin) plugin.

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.primefaces:maven-jsf-plugin:1.3.2 or one of its dependencies could
>   not be resolved: Failure to find
>   org.primefaces:maven-jsf-plugin:jar:1.3.2 in
>   http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/ was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of redhat-techpreview-all-repository has elapsed or updates
>   are forced

Ok, I can import it manually and add dependency later, so I continued installation and downloaded a dependency but get a bunch of errors:

For example class `DialogActionListener` located at path `src.main.java.org.primefaces.application` but according to source code should be located at `package org.primefaces.application;`

In *.xml files there's an error `The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

I suspect that I'm on a wrong direction but can't find out the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I've found your question and this solution when I was facing the same problem, I hope it helps someone else (It might be a little late for you):
Adding the following snippet to the pom.xml solves the issue.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>primeFaces_repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: where to add these lines?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is well described in the [PrimeFaces repository's Wiki](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Building-From-Source):

> There's a custom maven plugin to generate jsf artifacts. To begin you might need to check out and build PrimeFaces maven-jsf-plugin in case the version used is not available in Prime Repository.
>
> #### Build and Install maven-jsf-plugin
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/primefaces/maven-jsf-plugin.git
> ```
>
> cd to the maven-jsf-plugin directory
>
> ```
> cd maven-jsf-plugin
> mvn clean install
> ```