# How can I use Primefaces in my project as source code not as jar file?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

For example I have downloaded [Primefaces's source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces) and imported it in Eclipse as self-project.

Now I want to create a *regular JSF project* and make it use *Primefaces's components* by using mentioned earlier Primefaces's project and not importing Primeface's jar, is it possible?

What I want to achieve is to e*dit the Primefaces's code* and see the changes on the fly, after I'll be satisfied with a result I will compile it in a jar.

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**: added picture to display what do I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: the link in my answer is even a duplicate I think

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse with m2e, it will, if you configure m2e to use [workspace projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688344/in-eclipse-m2e-how-to-reference-workspace-project), do this automatically. I use JBossTools as a complete addon to Eclipse. Very satisfied with this. But you DO need the dependency on PrimeFaces in your pom. Just make sure you refer to the custom version (if you rename the artifact or version number)

If you don't use maven, you can try plain eclipse project dependency. See [Eclipse - How to give dependency between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553677/eclipse-how-to-give-dependency-between-projects)

Comment: You mean if I create my project by using maven? Actually I've done all my projects without maven, all dependencies were downloaded and added to build path manually, so I've no experience at all to work with the maven. I'm lack a basic knowledge of how all works under the hood. Have tried to use m2e but encountered a lot problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247933/how-to-import-primefacess-into-eclipse-as-source-code I'll try to follow tutorial which you mentioned in you answer. And then I'll give feedback. Thank you.

Comment: It'd be good if someone has made step-by-step tutorial how to do it. As far as I know a lot peoples have decent troubles with a maven, and if Primefaces is interesting in getting help from community in form of pull requests they should make it easy as possible.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very strange comment. More than 99.9% of the people that compile PrimeFaces to provide patches or for private use, use maven. And very few have problems with this. So creating a manual on how to do things without maven is a waste of time.

Comment: I get it, already installed maven and learning to work with it. Also I installed m2e and tried to import a Primefaces's source code, it get a lot errors. Can't find for example `jsf-maven-plugin` dependency etc. If I understand right I should (can?) compile this plugin manually and then in Primefaces's `pom.xml` reference it locally, am I right?

Comment: This plugin is in the primefaces repository, but yes you could also just compile it. This plugin then creates the 'missing' classes